# Smooth and analytic structures on low dimensional euclidian spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-topology, difference-equations

So it is relatively easy to show that there exists only one smooth structure on 
the real line $\mathbb{R}$. So here are 2 natural questions:

Q1: Up to equivalence, is there only one real analytic structure on $\mathbb{R}$? If so,
then do we have a simple proof of that?

Q2: Where can I find the simplest proofs that there exists only one smooth structure
on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$?

So I've heard that on $\mathbb{R}^4$ there are infinitly (in fact uncountably) many non-equivalent smooth structures, so what about real analytic strucutres? Is there some kind of moduli space of smooth structures on $\mathbb{R}^4$. if so, in how many ways is it possible to deform
a smooth structure into a real analytic one?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8789/can-every-manifold-be-given-an-analytic-structure

Comment: Thanks a lot Steven for the link. So do you know of a simple proof
that there exists only one real analytic structure on $\mathbb{R}$
which is compatible with its smooth structure?

Comment: Grauert-Remmert is probably irrelevant for this simple case.

Comment: It was my (offhand) impression that every topological group with underlying space an $\mathbb{R}$-manifold had a unique structure as a real-analytic Lie group (and that this is part of the Gleason-Montgomery-Zippin theory).  This is at least one attractive uniqueness result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding Q1, put an analytic Riemann metric on your 1-manifold.  Integrating a unit speed vector field gives an analytic diffeomorphism to $\mathbb R$.  Another way to prove analytic structures are unique is to notice the same argument that one uses to prove that the group of $C^k$-diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb R$ has the homotopy type of $\mathbb Z_2$ works for analytic diffeomorphisms -- simply take the straight-line homotopy between your original diffeomorphism and either the identity or the negative identity, appropriately.

Regarding Q2, I don't know much in the way of really simple proofs.  But when $n=2$ you've got the Uniformization Theorem from complex analysis.  That's relatively simple.

Comment: Hi Ryan, may be I miss something here, but how do you put an analytic
Riemann metric on a smooth manifold? Usually you piece your local inner products using a partition of unity which forces you to work in the smooth setting.

Comment: You put the analytic Riemann metric on the analytic manifold.  The flow from the ODE gives you an analytic diffeomorphism to $\mathbb R$ with its standard (analytic) structure.  

Comment: It is not obvious that there is an analytic metric on a given analytic manifold, since you can't use partitions of unity. Your analytic diffeomorphism is only to some interval of the real number line, because you haven't ensured completeness of your metric.