# Complexification of smooth manifolds

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, real-analytic-structures

Given a $C^\infty$- smooth manifold $M$, is there a natural way to complexify it?

By this I mean finding a complex manifold $N$ and a smooth function $f:M\to N$ such that $df:T_xM\otimes \mathbb{C}\to T_{f(x)}N$ becomes an isomorphism for every $x\in M$. It seems that using the existence of analytic structure on any smooth manifold should imply this ([Can every manifold be given an analytic structure?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8789/can-every-manifold-be-given-an-analytic-structure)) but since I can't find a reference I am not sure whether this is true or not.
So my questions are

> **Q1.** Does $N$ always exist?
>
> **Q2.** If it does, is it unique in some sense?
>
> **Q3.** Where can I learn more about this (if this is already known)?

Comment: By a result of Tognoli, it follows that any real analytic space admits a Stein complexification. See A. Tognoli, *Proprietà globali degli spazi analitici reali*, http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02416802

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Thanks for your reply. Is there an english translation of the article mentioned. Also I am interested more in the case where $N$ is compact (assuming M is compact), but maybe this doesn't exist

Comment: unfortunately, I do not think any english translation is available.

Comment: A reference in English of the result that Francesco mentioned above is this:
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-322-84243-5_3

Comment: another paper on this topic is http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/647/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01389901.pdf?

Comment: @XiaoyangChen Thanks for your comment but unfortunately, the link for the article is broken. Can you rewrite it?

Comment: On Complexifications of Differentiable Manifolds , Inventiones math. 44, 49- 64 (1978)