# What is known about differentiable and analytic structures on the long line (and half-line)?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology

When reading about [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8789/can-every-manifold-be-given-an-analytic-structure) which recently became active for some reason, I wanted to make a comment, as a warning regarding non-metrizable manifolds, to the effect that the every $C^\infty$ structure on the long (half-)line is compatible with at least continuum-many $C^\omega$ (i.e., real-analytic) structures, something which I seemed to remember, but I wasn't sure and couldn't remember a reference.  The [Wikipedia article on the long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29) states that “any given $C^\infty$ structure can be extended in infinitely many ways to different $C^\omega$ (=analytic) structures (which are pairwise non-diffeomorphic as analytic manifolds)”, but the reference given, viꝫ. the 1960 paper by H. Kneser & M. Kneser, “Reell-analytische Strukturen der Alexandroff-Halbgeraden und der Alexandroff-Geraden” (*Archiv der Mathematik* **11** 104–106), as far as I can make it, only seems to support the weaker claim (Satz 5) that there are multiple analytic structures, not how many there are, nor any relation with a predetermined $C^\infty$ structure (the paper says nothing about $C^\infty$).  The other paper cited in the Wikipedia article, by P. J. Nyikos, “Various smoothings of the long line and their tangent bundles”, *Advances in Math.* **93** (1992) 129–213, doesn't mention analytic structures at all except to note in the introduction that they can exist.  So now I am completely confused as to what is known (perhaps as a folklore result with no precise reference).  Specifically:

**Question:** Given $r<s$ in $\{0,1,2,\ldots,\infty,\omega\}$, how many different $C^s$ structures on the long line (or half-line) can exist that are compatible with a given $C^r$ structure?  What are the most precise known results in this direction, and, specifically, is it correct that, as Wikipedia claims, for $r=\infty$ and $s=\omega$, every $C^\infty$ structure admits infinitely many different $C^\omega$ structures that are compatible with it? Are there other references than the two papers cited in Wikipedia (citations reproduced above)?

Comment: When you say "how many", you mean modulo what? Because if you push forward the $C^s$-structure by a non-$C^s$ $C^r$-diffeomorphism, you get another one. So you might mean "modulo $C^r$-diffeomorphism".

Comment: What I am asking is, given a $C^r$-diffeomorphism class $L$ of $C^r$ “manifolds” that have the long line as underlying topological space, what is the cardinality of the set of $C^s$-diffeomorphism classes of $C^s$ “manifolds” that have $L$ as underlying $C^r$ “manifold”. This number should be given in function of $r<s$ — and possibly $L$ if this matters. (So depending on what you mean by “modulo”, this is modulo $C^r$ or $C^s$. I think we've had this exact discussion nine months ago, and my position is still the same. )

Comment: Oh yes it amounts to the same: (1) $\mathrm{Diff}^r(X)$-orbits on the set of $C^s$-structures on $X$ extending the given $C^r$-structure, and (2) (all manifolds $C^r$-diffeomorphic to $X$) modulo $C^s$-diffeomorphism.